# How to determine the activation energy for donors/acceptors using the Arrhenius eq.?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, ionization-energy

I am trying to determine the donor/acceptor activation energy for the semiconductor InGaP with the Arrhenius equation. However it contains only one parameter for the activation energy, which turns out to be around $55$meV when fitted on my measurements. Does that mean that this is the activation energy for both donor and acceptor or how can I discern them?

When I make the approximation based on the hydrogen atom I get 2 very different ionization energies:

$E_c - E_d = 8.7$ meV (donor)

$E_v - E_a = 69.5$ meV (acceptor)

(obtained by modifying the hydrogen energy with $\epsilon_{InGaP} = 11.8 \epsilon_0$ instead of $\epsilon_0$, $m_e^*=0.088 m_e$ and $m_h=0.7 m_e$ instead of $m_e$. Data was found in the NSM archive for $T=300$K)

Answer (score 1):

When you have either n-type InGaP or p-type InGaP, you need only one Arrhenius plot for the donor or acceptor activation energy in the temperature range where the freeze-out of the donors or acceptors occurs. You cannot determine both ionization energies in a semiconductor that is either n-ytype or p-type..

Comment: thank you for your answer. Does that mean that in my case I can compare the theoretical estimation and the fit parameter, and from that conclude that my InGaP sample is a p-type semiconductor?

Comment: @Julien - Usually, the ionization energy estimate using  modified hydrogen atom model gives only a very rough estimate. Maybe you can find also some experimental data on donor/acceptor ionization energies in InGaAs.Even though it is probably p-type,  I would be reluctant to use an impurity activation energy to identify the conduction type of a semiconductor. Too many things can happen in a semiconductor.Maybe you can do an independent determination of the conduction type, e.g., the simple hot-point probe test.  See e.g.,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot-point_probe